# How to load images from secured web site on anonymous web site

Tags: html, image, authentication, iis

I have a web site (Web Site A) that is hosting HTML files.  The HTML files contain image links that are hosted on another web site (Web Site B).  The web site B uses Windows authentication.  When a user requests a page on web site A, a network resource dialog pops up for authentication details.  I want the images to be loaded with the user having to enter authentication details.  I thought that if I run the app pool on web site A using a network login that has access to web site B, then the network resource dialog would not appear, but it still does.  Does anyone have any suggestions how I can keep web site A anonymous and load resources from web site B without the network login prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your users use IE and are logged on to their domain account

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258063

> The following conditions must be met for Internet Explorer to
>   automatically authenticate a user's logon and password and maintain
>   security:
>
> - Windows Integrated authentication, also known as Windows NT Challenge/Response, must be enabled in the Web site properties in IIS.
>     Anonymous authentication is attempted first, followed by Windows
>     Integrated authentication, Digest authentication (if applicable), and
>     finally Basic (clear text) authentication.
> - Both the client and the Web server must be either in the same Microsoft Windows NT-based or Microsoft Windows 2000-based domain or
>     in trusted Windows NT-based or Windows 2000-based domains in which the
>     user's account can be granted permissions to resources on the
>     IIS-based computer.
> - The user's browser must be Internet Explorer. Internet Explorer is the only browser that supports Windows Integrated authentication
>     (NTCR).
> - Internet Explorer must consider the requested URL to be on the intranet (local). If the computer name portion of the requested URL
>     contains periods (such as http://www.microsoft.com and
>     http://10.0.0.1), Internet Explorer assumes that the requested address
>     exists on the Internet and does not pass any credentials
>     automatically. Addresses without periods (such as http://webserver)
>     are considered to be on the intranet (local); Internet Explorer passes
>     credentials automatically. The only exception is addresses included in
>     the Intranet zone in Internet Explorer.
> - Internet Explorer's Intranet zone security setting must be set to Automatic logon only in Intranet zone. This is the default setting for
>     Internet Explorer.
>
> For additional information about Internet Explorer security zones,
>   click the article number below to view the article in the Microsoft
>   Knowledge Base:
>
> 174360 How to Use Security Zones in Internet Explorer
>
> - The user requesting the Web page must have appropriate file system (NTFS) permissions to the Web page as well as all of the objects
>     referenced in the Web page. For example, a user may have Full Control
>     rights to a Web page, but is prompted for a password if the Web page
>     refers to graphics that are in a secure folder.

Comment: This needs to work for unauthenticated users in any browser

Comment: it can't without some backend logic. You could make a backend server process that authenticates as user, then downloads the requested file, writes it to your server harddisk, then serves that file to the user.